# Unit test renderTags prop of Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, formik

I have been stuck trying to unit test the `renderTags` property of a mui `Autocomplete` component. I created a custom component which uses this. But I can't figure out how to unit test it. Below I'll show you what I have tried so far.

The component looks like this:

```
function ChipInput(props: Props): ReactElement {
  const [field, meta, { setValue }] = useField<string[]>(props.name);
  const errorText = (meta.touched && meta.error) || undefined;

  const handleChange = useCallback((_, value) => setValue(value), [setValue]);

  const renderTags = (value: string[], getTagProps) =>
    value.map((option: string, index: number) => (
      <Chip variant="outlined" label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
    ));

  const renderInput = params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="filled"
      label={props.label}
      error={errorText !== undefined}
      helperText={errorText || props.helperText}
    />
  );

  return (
    <Column column={props.column}>
      <Autocomplete
        id={`chipInput-${props.name}`}
        multiple
        options={[]}
        value={field.value || []}
        onChange={handleChange}
        freeSolo
        renderTags={renderTags}
        renderInput={renderInput}
      />
    </Column>
  );
}
```

And this is how I am currently trying to unit test it. It works like this for `renderInput` but not for `renderTags`:

```
describe('ChipInput', () => {
  const useFieldMock = jest.spyOn(Formik, 'useField');
  const flavours = mockUseField<unknown>(['salt', 'paprika']);

  const props: ComponentProps<typeof ChipInput> = {
    name: 'chipInput',
    label: 'Chip input',
    column: 1,
  };

  it('should render chips', () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    useFieldMock.mockReturnValue(flavours);

    const component = shallow(<ChipInput {...props} />);
    const autocomplete = component.find(Autocomplete);

    console.log(autocomplete.prop('value'));
    const renderTags = autocomplete.prop('renderTags') as () => ReactElement;
    const input = shallow(renderTags());

    expect(input).toExist();
  });
});
```

In the console log, I can see `[ 'salt', 'paprika' ]` printed, so I know the value has been set correctly. But somehow, on `shallow(renderTags())` it throws the error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, because apparently in `renderTags` the value param is still empty. Even though as seen in the console log, it has been set.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I feel I must misunderstand something. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you take `autocomplete.prop('renderTags')` it returns the `renderTags` function that you defined in the component as is. And its type is not `() => ReactElement` but `(value: string[], getTagProps: Function) => ReactElement[]`. Then you call `renderTags` without arguments, `value` is `undefined`, and you get the error when `value.map(...)` is executed. To fix the issue you need to pass a proper set of arguments:

```js
// I've made the second argument(getTagProps) return an empty object
// update with what you expect
const input = shallow(renderTags(['salt', 'paprika'], () => ({})));
```

In general, I would suggest moving `renderTags` out of the component and making it exportable, so it can be tested in isolation. This would make testing way easier(no need to render the entire component).

Comment: Thanks! Can you expand your code snippet? I still can't get it to work, but I probably am still missing something else

Comment: @jbrulmans can you show what you're getting now? I don't know what exactly `getTagProps` should return. A proper mock might be the answer

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I took the `renderTags()` out of the component to test it by itself like you suggested 

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it by passing arguments like this..

```
const component = shallow(<ChipInput {...props} />);

const autocomplete = component.find(Autocomplete);

autocomplete.at(0).prop('renderTags')(['salt', 'paprika'],{})
```